# CSS Floating ScrollTop button Not Clickable on top of iframe

Tags: javascript, css

i have floating button with fixed position, but when button position location over an iframe (disqus or etc) i cant click my button. How i can make that button clickable when positioned over iframe? i set my z-index 9999 on button and z-index 1 on iframe but still cant get it work.

```
|                         |
|                         |
|                         |
|    Very Tall Iframe     |
|------                   |
|Button|                  |
|------                   |
```

.CSS

```
.up {
    z-index: 9999;
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 70px;
    right: 23px;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 2px;
}

iframe {
    width: 1px !important;
    min-width: 100% !important;
    border: none !important;
    overflow: hidden !important;
    height: 1973px !important;
    z-index: 1;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It **do** work in my browser

```css
.up {
    z-index: 9999;
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 70px;
    right: 23px;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 2px;
}

iframe {
    width: 1px !important;
    min-width: 100% !important;
    border: none !important;
    overflow: hidden !important;
    height: 1973px !important;
    z-index: 1;
    }
```

```html
<iframe></iframe>
<button class="up" onclick="alert('success')">Button</button>
```